# ROSmatlab + hydro + ardrone

Tags: ros, matlab, rosmatlab, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use hydro from matlab 2013a on ubuntu.  I've so far installed ROS, and the autonomy/ardrone code, as well as the ardrone_tutorials code and verified both work from the command line (i.e. I can roslaunch the demo code, control the drone, etc).

What I need to do next is set up a node in rosmatlab, which I believe I did correctly after setting environment variables etc:

node = rosmatlab.node('NODE','localhost',11311);  % This completes correctly

When I try to add a subscriber, I see an error in the terminal window in which I'm running the drone driver, which leads me to assume the above line is correct.  The problem is that rosmatlab does not seem to know what a message of type navdata is, thus the following fails:

sub = rosmatlab.subscriber('ardrone/navdata','ardrone_autonomy/Navdata',1,node);

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ardrone_autonomy.Navdata.

I'm not sure how to proceed.  Do I need to somehow port the existing code into matlab?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164376/rosmatlab-+-hydro-+-ardrone/) by [Dr One](https://answers.ros.org/users/17946/dr-one/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since rosmatlab is based on rosjava, it sounds like the messages you're using haven't been built for Java.

These tutorials may be useful:

- http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Messages
- http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/hydro/Unofficial%20Messages

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dr One](https://answers.ros.org/users/17946/dr-one/) on 2014-05-14**:
Many thanks for taking the time to answer, I believe you are quite correct.  Unfortunately building a custom message package seems fairly onerous given the present state of rosjava. Nevertheless, thanks a lot :)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-14**:
You shouldn't have to create a custom message package; you just need to compile the messages in the existing ardrone_autonomy package for rosjava.

**Comment by [Dr One](https://answers.ros.org/users/17946/dr-one/) on 2014-05-15**:
I figured that out a little before seeing your comment.  Happy to say that a quick crash course on Gradle and rosjava builds saved the day.  Now I'm just trying to figure servces and rosmatlab out...